# Trying to update parameters sent to URL to change contents of iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am using an iframe to display a map from a 3rd part website. Following the web address to the map (in the URL) is a # followed by the number representing the zoom level, an latitude and longitude for the center of the map separated by backslashes, as such: `http://URL.html#zoom/lat/long`

I am using javascript to update the contents of the `iframe` by updating the src. However, since the web address is the same, when I try to update the `iframe` by changing the lat, long or zoom parameters within the URL, nothing changes. I tried inserting code before updating the URL to the correct new value that firsts changes the `src` to a dummy `src` ("about:blank") this kind of solved the problem, but the buttons that updated the `src` had to be clicked twice to make it actually work. Has anyone else had a similar problem, or know of a workaround?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a random parameter before the hash:

```
http://URL.html?rand=123#zoom/lat/long
```

123 could for example be a timestamp.